# how to stop visual studio 2013 from adding mapping source link to css files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I'm using visual studio 2013.

I'm using the web essential tool for my less/css files.

when I'm saving a less file it's add a line like the one below to the end css file,for example:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=filename.css.map */
```

how can I stop the vs2013 from adding this?

I went to the web essential options and disable the option called: "create source map files" and I change it to false,it's not creating map files but still add the line above to the css file.

Comment: Step 1: Uninstall Web Essentials. Step 2: Win

Answer (score 8):

I am also using VS2013. And preprocessor SASS.
When I edit a file .scss that is updated .css file and the file appears .css.map that is added to the project.

It turned out that it tricks WEB-essential plugin.
Along this path

**Tools** > Options > Web Essentials > **SASS** > Create source map files = false

I was able to disable the automatic creation of files .css.map and

Also in the settings there is a way for LESS:
**Tools** > Options > Web Essentials > **LESS**

Comment: In VS2015 I don't see that option after installing Web Essentials.

Answer (score 0):

First remove all existing mappings from your code (find and delete lines starting with /*# sourceMappingURL= )

Then recompile using *WebEssentials > Re-compile all LESS files*

I had the same issue as you did and in my case this solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Project Create a (.vscode) Directory. In the .vscode folder create a json file named settings.json. Inside of the settings.json, type following key-value pairs. By the way you'll get intelli-sense. You can assign the key-value of "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap" true or false. I hope this will work

```
{
 "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/css"
    },
    {
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "format": "compressed",
        "savePath": "/dist/css"
    }
],    
"liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false,
"liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
]
}
```